# Able to request access token with from Azure AD, but also need refresh token

Tags: asp.net, azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am able to get an access token for my native application using POST to Azure AD via this method (from the official MS guide): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx

Per the example, if I send a request like this to the POST url:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[id]&client_secret=[secret]&resource=[resourceURI]
```

Then per the documentation, I only get the following fields (full JSON response below):

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "expires_on": "1428372149",
    "not_before": "1428368249",
    "resource": "http://myresource",
    "access_token": "asdfghjkl"
}
```

What I want is a refresh token as well. Is there a way to alter the request to get one?

Comment: Strangely enough, in the previous article, (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645538.aspx) it is written: 

"...if you are building a web service, follow the instructions in Service to Service Calls Using Client Credentials to get an access token AND A REFRESH TOKEN"

Which just points to the first article I referenced. Something seems to be missing...

Comment: can you paste the full JSON response you get from this request?

Comment: @starmandeluxe was this resolved? Please provide a solution if u have.